# Regression equation for peak fronting/tailing in chromatography

Tags: chromatography

## Background

I would like to have a sum of functions $$\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(x)$$ which approximates my chromatogram. The variable $x$ would be my retention time, although I don't mind if answers change it to $t$, $t_r$ or anything else they prefer.

One issue that arises is that the peaks are not always symmetric. This is called tailing or fronting:

- [Troubleshooting Basics, Part IV: Peak Shape Problems](https://www.chromatographyonline.com/view/troubleshooting-basics-part-iv-peak-shape-problems)

## Effort

Fiddling around in Desmos I came up with a sort of "split-variance Gaussian function" to model a single peak. Or at  least that's the name I made up writing this post.

[image]

(Sorry for using an image. The $\LaTeX$ wasn't rendering correctly.. Feel free to edit: `$$f(x; a, m, s_1, s_2) = \begin{cases}a\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-m}{s_1}\right)^{2}\right) & x \leq m \\ a\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-m}{s_2}\right)^{2}\right) & x > m \end{cases}$$`)

This seems to

- have relatively few parameters per peak
- give fronting or tailing depending on the pair $(s_1, s_2)$
- $\lim_{x \rightarrow m^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow m^+} f(x) = f(m) = a$
- $\arg\max_x f = m$

But I know that just b/c I have an attempt that superficially serves the purpose doesn't mean that someone hasn't come up with something better. I'm looking for what a chromatographer would use (rather than my mathematical guesswork).

## Question

Are there conventional mathematical models for asymmetric peaks on chromatograms? If not, would my split-variance Gaussian function be alright from a chemist's point of view?

Comment: It depends on the regression method too.

Comment: @ananta Oh [NUTS](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/nuts.pdf) that is a good point.

Comment: You also need the tops of the peaks to touch. So the two equations need different a's, i.e. $a_1 \ne a_2$.

Comment: You could try this equation and vary $N$ and $p$. The shape of a chromatogram is closely related to the Poisson distribution  
$\displaystyle P(n) = p\frac{(np)^{(N-1)}}{(N-1)!}e^{-np} $ where $N$ is the number of theoretical plates, $p$ the probability related to the partition constant $K$ the total volume of the mobile phase $V_m$ and of $V_s$ the stationary phase,$\displaystyle p=\left(1+K\frac{V_s}{V_m}\right)^{-1}$(chapter 4 in chemistry-maths-book.com)

Comment: Maybe this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: @MaxW I don't think that is necessary. The function is continuous and at its maximum when the case switches.

Comment: @porphyrin [Theoretical plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_plate) is not necessarily an integer  (although it does appear to be non-negative) so putting it in a factorial is undefined except in rather special cases. But maybe extending to the non-negative real numbers using the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) might be fine. Would have to check that the normalization is fine under this generalization.

Comment: Actually, the normalization isn't important in this case.